# What can you expect if you repeat a variable condition in two different else-ifs?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have the following:

```
string compararcom610b;
//Variables.Gcombinadofavdesf is defined in another class

if (something)
{
}
else if (Variables.Gcombinadofavdesf == 1)
{
    //do stuff_1
}
else if (compararcom610b == "1" && Variables.Gcombinadofavdesf == 1)
{
    //do stuff_2
}
```

Assuming that in this right moment `compararcom610b = 1` and `Variables.Gcombinadofavdef = 1`, 
will the `stuff_1` be done as well as `stuff_2`?

Or will only `stuff_1` be done?

Comment: isn't it easier to just put a breakpoint and test it...

Comment: [Microsoft C# reference for if-else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

Comment: @Zdravko simply testing won't help me understand how it behaves, in different situations it could do something unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `else if` as soon as it enter in a block it will skip the others.

it will only execute stuff 1.

If you want both to be executed use this :

```
if (something)
{
}
else if (Variables.Gcombinadofavdesf == 1)
{
    //do stuff_1
}

if (compararcom610b == "1" && Variables.Gcombinadofavdesf == 1)
{
    //do stuff_2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Variables.Gcombinadofavdesf == 1, then do stuff_1.

Otherwise [else] if compararcom610b == "1" and Variables.Gcombinadofavdesf == 1, do stuff_2.

Does that make more sense?

The second condition on the second else if, the one that checks if Variables.Gcombinadofavdesf == 1 again, is redundant. If Variables.Gcombinadofavdesf == 1 the first check for its value will result in the second else-if being skipped. If it's false, the second check will be false as well.

In an if else-if else-if ... else statement combo, only one will ever be executed. You can think of each extra else-if as being a backup plan if the if before it fails.